# Reading in Partial InputStream

Tags: java, inputstream

I'm looking to read an InputStream in sections because I need the first n bytes of the file and last m bytes as well as the contents between.

`byte[] beginning = inputStream.readNBytes(16);`

This works just fine, but to get the last m bytes, I tried the following:

```
byte[] middle = inputStream.readNBytes(inputStream.available() - 32);
byte[] end = inputStream.readNBytes(inputStream.available());
```

The end variable looks how I expect it to but not the middle variable, which ends up cutting out part of the stream.

I'm also a bit confused why the buf parameter size in the input stream doesn't seem to be equal to the byte array size when converting one to the other.

Anyway, I assume this isn't working how I want it to because (inputStream.available() - 32) is not adding up to a value compatible with readNBytes, so part of the stream is lost.

Is there a way to go about doing this?

EDIT: What I ended up doing which seemed to work(mostly) is when creating the file, to prepend both pieces I will later be extracting instead of prepending one and appending the other.  That way I can just call inputStream.readAllBytes() on the last piece.

I also had to change where I'm writing to the file. I was writing to a CipherOutputStream when I should've been writing to the FileOutputStream and using that to create the Cipher OS.

Even after doing this I still have an extra 16 bytes at the end of the file, which confuses me, but I can easily ignore that last bit if I can't figure out why it's doing that.

Comment: According the the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()), `available` _Returns an **estimate** of the number of bytes that can be read_

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that can be read **without blocking**

Comment: I would read the whole stream...